# Access to an array integer from a function

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to write the integers from an array in a function, it always shows "The name '(array name)' does not exist in the current context"

```
int counter = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
int[] nums = new int[counter];
while (counter > 0)
{
    nums[counter] = counter;
    counter--;
 }
```

(basiclly created an array with the length that the user chose and put the numbers from 1 to counter in the array)
*after some code that changes whats in the array's integers*
(counter does not change)

```
print(counter);
```

a function i created

```
public static void print(int count);
{
    *some code*
    while (count > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(nums[count]); //line with the error
        count--;
    } 

}
```

I was expecting it to write the integers in nums array but it didn't.
(btw I need to write it inside the function, I call it later in the code)

Comment: Why do you have boxs[] and nums[] ? It looks a bit like you confused the two. Do please post the full code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it means that your array not in the context of the function so it can't "see" it. Either you have to declare it in the function, make accessible via some field in a class or pass it as a parameter

```
public static void print(int[] nums, int count)
{...}
```

Answer (score 0):

> "The name '(array name)' does not exist in the current context"

As the error suggests your function isn't able to find the array in the function context (because it's outside the function itself).

In order to find it you have two options:

```
print(counter, nums)
public static void print(int count, int[] nums)
{...}
```

Or wrap everything in a class:

```
class Program
{
    static int[] nums; 
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int counter = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] nums = new int[counter];
        while (counter > 0)
        {
            nums[counter] = counter;
            counter--;
        }
        print(counter);
    }
    public static void print(int count)
    {
        // some code
        while (count > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(nums[count]); //line with the error
            count--;
        }
    }
}
```